# jQuery Mobile horizontal button group is displayed incorrectly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with buttons not showing up correctly in a horizontal control group. Here is how it is supposed to work:

[image: Buttons Displayed Correctly]

After logging in, the Logout button uses a form with a submit button and it is not getting displayed correclty. Here is what I am getting:

[image: Buttons Displayed Incorrectly]

I can't figure out why because the markup seems to be correct, but Chrome is not interpretting it correclty. Here is what Chrome is computing for the CSS:

[image]

Why does Chrome show that it should use `inline-block` but is still using `block`?

Here is the markup source:

```
<div style="float:right;margin-right: 25px;">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="float:right;display:inline;">
        <a class="username" data-ajax="false" data-inline="true" data-role="button" href="/Account/Manage" id="manageLink" title="Manage">admin</a>
        <form action="/Account/Logout" data-ajax="false" id="logoutForm" method="post">
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="" />
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" id="logoutLink" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Logout</a>
        </form>    
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the applied markup in Chrome's element inspector:

```
<div style="float:right;margin-right: 25px;">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="float:right;display:inline;" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="false" data-corners="true" data-exclude-invisible="true" data-mini="false" data-init-selector=":jqmData(role='controlgroup')">
        <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
            <a class="username ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-first-child" data-ajax="false" data-inline="true" data-role="button" href="/Account/Manage" id="manageLink" title="Manage" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">admin</span></span></a>
            <form action="/Account/Logout" data-ajax="false" id="logoutForm" method="post">
                <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="">
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" id="logoutLink" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-last-child ui-btn-up-a">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Logout</span></span></a>
            </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The resultant markup seems to have all the proper jQuery Mobile classes to make it look right: `btn-inline` and `ui-last-child`. Not sure what is causing the problem. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a FORM element within the controlgroup. The best solution would be to remove the FORM element and just handle the logout button click without it.

If you really want to keep the FORM, you can override some CSS to make it look right:

```
[data-role="controlgroup"] form {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
[data-role="controlgroup"] form .ui-last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5em !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em !important;    
}
```

Make FORMs within a controlgroup display inline with a left float, and make the right corners rounded on the button inside the form

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/r3vqqg5h/)**

Comment: I was thinking it had something to do with the form because the login version doesn't use the form. The form is there mostly to provide the verification for authentication. I will modify the necessary CSS elements to force it to look right under these conditions.